# Editing keys in a plist dictionary?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, string, xcode

I am writing a word puzzle game. I want to have a plist file where i keep track of the users solutions to my puzzles. In other words, I want to save data whenever the user finishes or pauses a level.

The game consists of 20 levels in each of 5 categories (so 100 levels total). The questions are loaded from a plist when the user starts the game. The objective is basically to unscramble the message and i want them to be able to come back to started levels later. Their solutions must then be stored in some sort of editable (mutable?) array.

I'm fairly new to coding and I've looked online but didn't find any answers. I just dont know how to implement it.

**My Question**: If I create a .plist file to store the users' solutions (with 5 array keys for each category, each array having a set of 20 blank string values) is it possible to edit entries as the user plays the levels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to write an NSDictionary or NSArray to a .plist file using the method

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag
```

So, why not load your state information from the plist into an array, each containing an NSMutableDictionary with the user's answers. Then, when the user sets a new answer, set a new object for that question key. When finished, write the parent NSArray to file using the method above - voila.

EDIT - NSArray would work better in this instance

Comment: i think that makes sense. what do you mean by state information? the existing information for the level from my old plist? thanks for the great answer

Comment: Correct. So you load your information from the file into memory (in the form of an NSArray of NSDictionarys), then overwrite the file when you need to. You might want to frequently save, else make sure that you're covered if your app gets terminated due to memory or worse still, crashes.